# Doctrine 2 find pages having attributes

Tags: php, mysql, sql, doctrine-orm, dql

I need to fill query builder with filter conditions of page attributes. I got Enities "Page", "Attribute" and "Value"

```
Page: id, name, etc
Attribute: id, name, etc
Value: page_id, date, string, numeric
```

I need to get all pages having attribute values selected in form.

So i get Query Builder:

```
$qb->select('p')
   ->from(Page p)
   ->leftJoin(p.values);
```

Can I use "having" or "where" clauses to do like?

```
$qb->add('having', 'a.id = :attr1_id AND a.value = :attr1_val')
$qb->add('having', 'a.id = :attr2_id AND a.value = :attr2_val')
```

UPDATE: No i can't. in this way it can get page with attr1_id = attr2_value AND attr2_id = attr1_value and all conditions will be true, but result is wrong.

or I should add custom join for each value?

UPDATE: here's working exapmle:

```
//attr1.intval=:a1 (or LIKE, BETWEEN, etc compare)
$comp_expression=$aliace.'.'.$value_field.'=:a'.$this->getId();
//INNER JOIN attribute attr1 ON attr1.type=5 AND attr1.intval=:a1
$qb->innerJoin($value_class, $aliace , 'WITH', $aliace.'.type='.$this->getId().' AND '.$comp_expression);
//where attr1.intval IS NOT NULL
$qb->andWhere($aliace.'.'.$value_field.' IS NOT NULL');
$qb->setParameter('a'.$this->getId(),$value);
```

UPDATE: So **the only way to do key+value filtring is to add join for each filter condition? I got 27 attributes now, so need to build query with 27 joins?**

**Is there another way to this better?** Sorry if this is duplicate, cant find keywords to find same questions.

UPDATE: Maybe i shuld get out of sql query limits and create mysql procedure for it?

UPDATE: **Can i use somthing like this in doctrine?** [MySQL optimization on filtering key-value pairs as records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890135/mysql-optimization-on-filtering-key-value-pairs-as-records)

Comment: Are you searching for pages that *exactly match* the given attributes; that contain *all* of the given attributes; that match *any* of the given attributes; or might the logic be more complicated?

Comment: just matching all given attributes

Comment: but value can be not exec match, but BETWEEN expression or %LIKE%. "values" table has date,string and numeric fields, in "attribute" class specefied mapping to real field name in value, so its not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Model

The model you are using here is called [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) (EAV). If you weren't aware of that I suggest you read about the pro's and con's first.

One of the con's is that searching in a EAV model is difficult and very inefficient.

#### AND queries

It seems you want to query for Entities that have a specific Value for a specific Attribute **and** another specific Value for a specific Attribute. These types of queries are *not* very efficient in the EAV model.

Let's assume your entities are set up as:

```
Entity:    id, attributes (one-to-many), values (one-to-many)
Attribute: id, name, entity (many-to-one), values (one-to-many)
Value:     id, content, entity (many-to-one), attribute (many-to-one)
```

Let's assume you want to query for all Entities that have an Attribute `color` with the value `blue`. A Doctrine query would look like this:

```
SELECT e FROM Entity e
JOIN e.values v JOIN v.attribute a
WHERE a.name = 'color' AND v.content = 'blue'
```

(Of course you should never use values in the DQL like this, but bind them as parameters.)

Now let's assume you want to query for all Entities that have an Attribute `color` with the value `blue` **and** an Attribute `shape` with the value `square`. The query becomes:

```
SELECT e FROM Entity e
JOIN e.values v1 JOIN v.attribute a1
JOIN e.values v2 JOIN v.attribute a2
WHERE a1.name = 'color' AND v1.content = 'blue'
AND a2.name = 'shape' AND v2.content = 'square'
```

Now if you want to query for 3 Attribute/Value pairs, you'll need 3 of those JOIN sets. If you want to query for 4 Attribute/Value pairs, you'll need 4 of those JOIN sets. Etc.

#### OR queries

Let's assume you want to query for all Entities that have an Attribute `color` with the value `blue` **or** an Attribute `shape` with the value `square`. The query becomes:

```
SELECT e FROM Entity e
JOIN e.values v JOIN v.attribute a
WHERE (a.name = 'color' AND v.content = 'blue')
OR (a.name = 'shape' AND v.content = 'square')
```

You can see this is more efficient, you won't need those additional JOIN sets for every additional Attribute/Value pair.

#### Mixing AND OR

I'm going to be short here: this will become a query nightmare. I strongly advise you *not* to do this.

#### Alternative

If your application is going to rely heavily on these types of queries (especially AND and mixing AND OR), I suggest you consider a different type of storage engine. Relational Databases are not really suited for this kind of thing.

You'll probably be better of using a [Document Oriented Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document-oriented_database), something like [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.com/), [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/), etc.

#### Hybrid alternative

You can also "copy" the EAV part to a Document Oriented Database and use it only for search functionality. I suggest you set up events for when changes are made to an Entity (create, update, delete). Then create listeners that persist those changes into the Document store.

This way your application can work with the Relational Database for normal operations, and the Document store for searching. In this case I advise [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), which is extremely suitable for this kind of thing.

Comment: thanks! You filled whitespaces in my knowlege of this structure. Thats realy usefull information for me. I can't move project to nosql database and hope i'll never be requested to build  queries with AND/OR mixes.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you move the entire Relational Database to a Document Database, just the part that uses the EAV model ;) Or you can "copy" that part to a Document Database and use it only for searching (I'll update my answer).

Comment: I can just convert attributes into json attribute filed and use for filtering, I think thats exacly what i need, cose all pages allredy used in sphinx index for search i just need to create EAV to JSON convertion, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

There is no such difference between the two methods, the two methods do exactly the same thing.

By the central point of question, I got the doubt is about the construction of query using like.

The first example you provide is workfull.
The second example you propose is not right.

On the second example, you need to define All the where clauses on andWhere method.

```
$qb->innerJoin('a1 ON p.id=a1.page_id');
$qb->andWhere('a1.attribute_id=:attr1_id ');
$qb->andWhere('a1.value=:attr1_val');
$qb->andWhere('a1 is not null');
```

All are you doing is creating a sql by a third api, Doctrine ORM is one of the most successful orm tool for php, knowing how to use it will let you to experience the ORM power, by doctrine implementation all you need to know are there:

Doctrine Create Query Builder -> The same are you using.

[Doctrine Query Builder](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

Doctrine Create Query -> Simplest form

[Query Language](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)

Comment: "having" clause is far not the same. As for mysql its absolutly defferent operations cose them processed on different stages and work with different datasets. "Where" clause works on table of contents, but "Having" works on results table. Also its bad idea to filter joined table contents in "Where" clause when we can filter data on join stage using ON operator (thats performance difference between join and multytable query). But thanks anyway, you pushed my to the right way.

Comment: maybe you shall try to read those documentation and re factoring your question.